# Overstaying tourist visa Chile awaiting temp visa

Tags: visas, overstaying, chile

My sister went to Chile in Sept'18, she was there for two weeks, left for Costa Rica, returned for two weeks, left for Ecuador then came back to Chile and has been there since.

I understand the tourist visa is 180 days from entering but we're not sure if that's from the first day she entered in Sept or the last time she went back in November. Either way, her tourist visa has now expired.

She applied for a 'temporary visa'? Something like that but hasn't heard back from them and is now looking to come home. Would she have to pay a fine for overstaying even though she applied for another visa in November and hasn't heard back or would she be free to leave without a penalty?

Comment: Has your sister contacted Immigration to follow up on her ‘temporary visa’ application? Waiting nearly 6 months for a reply doesn’t seem credible. From this website https://www.extranjeria.gob.cl/ingles/prorroga_turismo.html it seems a tourist visa can be extended for 90 days, which is now well past. From https://www.extranjeria.gob.cl/ingles/sanciones.html fines are payable for overstaying https://www.extranjeria.gob.cl/ingles/filesapp/TABLA%20DE%20SANCIONES%202007_2008.pdf

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me, she has been told it's in progress but nothing more than that. Her boyfriend, born in Chile, has been arranging everything but personally I wouldn't trust him as far I could throw him (in the nicest way possible). He explained she had to pay half the fee up front then the rest when it arrives but she isn't being told anything more than it's in progress. I'm assuming there she is able to contact immigration/consulate without being penalised if what she has been informed so far is incorrect... Please forgive my ignorance!

Comment: I’ve never been to Chile but I have extended my tourist visa in other Latin American countries. According to the Extranjería site I linked to above, the visa extension fee is equal to US$100. I’d be dubious about it being paid in two parts, or that it takes more than a few days, unless I’d been told that personally by an Immigration official. Also, she should have applied for, and received, the extension before her initial entry permission expired. If that’s not happened, she may well be liable to pay the fine before she is given permission to leave.